# Определение часового пояса

Tags: javascript

Как можно определить часовой пояс пользователя (лучше время на PC в unix формате).
На сервере хранится время в `Unix` - формате (по Московскому времени)

Написана функция для выдачи в нормальный вид пользователю даты (есть поддержка `$uTimeZone`)/

Осталось определять какое время на PC? что бы выдавать по его времени дату

Answer (score 3):

```
x = new Date()
// Вычислим значение смещения текущего часового пояса в часах
currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = -x.getTimezoneOffset()/60

var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

[Описание на developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Answer (score 0):

```
now=new Date();
localtime=now.toString();
utctime=now.toGMTString();
```

Как то так!

Comment: Спасибо, но уже решил проблему.